# How to Group Matched Items

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, common-table-expression

Backstory:
I have created a bunch of stored procedures that analyze my client's data.  I am reviewing a list of vendors and trying to identify possible duplicates.  Thanks to DaleK the issue with the same records appearing in the results more than once is resolved, but now they are no longer grouped.

Process:
I created a "clean" version of the address where I remove special characters and normalize  to USPS standards.  This helps me match West v W v W. or PO Box v P.O. Box v P O Box etc.  I then take all of the distinct address values from both addresses (`[cleanAddress]` and `[cleanRemit_Address]`) and put into a master list.  I then compare to the source table with a `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` to determine which addresses appear more than once.  Lastly I take that final list of addresses that appear more than once and combine it with the source data for output.

Problem:
The CTE takes care of the issue where the same record would appear twice if matched on both `[cleanAddress]` and `[cleanRemit_Address]`.  However, now the dupe records are no longer grouped and they need to be for readability.  "INFINITY AND BEYOND" and "ZEEBO INC" have the same address but in a larger data set they would be hundreds or thousands of lines away making it very difficult to review and resolve.  I need a way to group the matched records for output.
Ordering by Name or one of the Address fields gets it close, but in the larger data set that I have, it would make a significant difference and create hours of additional work for the client.

- SSMS 18
- SQL Server 2019

Queries:

```
--SQL (Address List): Combines all addresses for a master list of all addresses in the table
SELECT * INTO [address_list] FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [NewAdd] FROM 
      (
        SELECT  DISTINCT [cleanAddress] AS [NewAdd]
          FROM [sample_data]
          WHERE 
            ( [cleanAddress] IS NOT NULL AND [cleanAddress] <> '' ) AND
            ( [Supplier_No]  IS NOT NULL  AND [Supplier_No] <> '' )
          GROUP BY [cleanAddress] 

        UNION 

        SELECT  DISTINCT [cleanRemit_Address] AS [NewAdd]
          FROM [sample_data]
          WHERE 
            ( [cleanRemit_Address] IS NOT NULL AND [cleanRemit_Address] <> '' ) AND
            ( [Supplier_No]  IS NOT NULL  AND [Supplier_No] <> '' )
          GROUP BY [cleanRemit_Address]
      ) q1
  ) q2 
ORDER BY 
  [NewAdd] 
  


--SQL (Address Dupes): Determines which addresses appear in the data more than once
SELECT * INTO [dupe_addresses] FROM (
    SELECT [NewAdd]
      FROM [address_list] n 
      LEFT JOIN [sample_data] pv ON 
      (
        ( n.[NewAdd] = pv.[cleanAddress]       AND ( [Address]       <> '' AND [Address]       IS NOT NULL ) )  OR
        ( n.[NewAdd] = pv.[cleanRemit_Address] AND ( [Remit_Address] <> '' AND [Remit_Address] IS NOT NULL ) )
      ) 
    WHERE 
      ( [Supplier_No] IS NOT NULL AND [Supplier_No] <> '' ) 
    GROUP BY [NewAdd] 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ) q1 
ORDER BY [NewAdd] 

 

--SQL (Address Query): Outputs the information of the matched addresses
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        'Address Match' AS [Reason], 
        pv.[Supplier_No], 
        pv.[Name], 
        pv.[Address], 
        pv.[City], 
        pv.[State], 
        pv.[Zip], 
        pv.[Country], 
        pv.[Remit_Address], 
        pv.[Remit_City], 
        pv.[Remit_State], 
        pv.[Remit_Zip], 
        pv.[Remit_Country]
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pv.[Supplier_No] ORDER BY pv.[Name]) rn
    FROM dupe_addresses n 
    LEFT JOIN sample_data pv 
        ON (
            (n.[NewAdd] = pv.[cleanAddress] AND ( [Address] <> '' AND [Address] IS NOT NULL ))
            OR (n.[NewAdd] = pv.[cleanRemit_Address] AND ( [Remit_Address] <> '' AND [Remit_Address] IS NOT NULL))
        ) 
    WHERE ([Supplier_No] IS NOT NULL AND [Supplier_No] <> '') 
)
INSERT INTO [dupecheck]
    SELECT
        'Address Match' AS [Reason], 
        [Supplier_No], 
        [Name], 
        [Address], 
        [City], 
        [State], 
        [Zip], 
        [Country], 
        [Remit_Address], 
        [Remit_City], 
        [Remit_State], 
        [Remit_Zip], 
        [Remit_Country]
      FROM cte
      WHERE rn = 1
    ORDER BY [Name];

--SQL (Address Query): Outputs the information of the matched addresses
SELECT * FROM [dupecheck]
```

Sample Data:

```
-- Output Table
CREATE TABLE [dupecheck] (
  [id] int identity(1, 1), 
  [Data Area] varchar(255), 
  [Supplier_No] varchar(255), 
  [Name] varchar(255), 
  [Address] varchar(255), 
  [City] varchar(255), 
  [State] varchar(255), 
  [Zip] varchar(255), 
  [Country] varchar(255), 
  [Remit_Address] varchar(255), 
  [Remit_City] varchar(255), 
  [Remit_State] varchar(255), 
  [Remit_Zip] varchar(255), 
  [Remit_Country] varchar(255), 
)

CREATE TABLE [sample_data] (
    [Supplier_No]           varchar(255),
    [Name]                  varchar(255),
    [Address]               varchar(255),
    [City]                  varchar(255),
    [State]                 varchar(255),
    [Zip]                   varchar(255),
    [Country]               varchar(255),
    [Remit_Address]         varchar(255),
    [Remit_City]            varchar(255),
    [Remit_State]           varchar(255),
    [Remit_Zip]             varchar(255),
    [Remit_Country]         varchar(255),
    [cleanAddress]          varchar(255),
    [cleanRemit_Address]    varchar(255),
    CONSTRAINT [suppliers_pk] PRIMARY KEY ([Supplier_No])
)

INSERT INTO [sample_data] VALUES
    ('1039104','Geez Companies','100 Aero Hudson Rd','Streetsboro','OH','44241','','100 Aero Hudson Road','Streetsboro','OH','44241','USA','100 Aero Hudson Rd','100 Aero Hudson Rd'),
    ('1218409','SouthWestern Medical','100 West Balor Ave','Osceola','AR','72370','USA','SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave','Osceola','AR','72370','USA','100 W Balor Ave','SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave'),
    ('1243789','SouthWestern Medical','100 West Balor Ave','Osceola','AR','72370','USA','SouthWestern Medical100 West Balor Ave','Osceola','AR','72370','USA','100 W Balor Ave','SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave'),
    ('1243636','SIRI SYSTEMS','15 BRAD ROAD','WEXFORD','PA','15090','','','','','','','15 BRAD RD',''),
    ('1152482','FLEETWOOD MACK','22 WINDSOCK CT','ADDISON','IL','60101','','PO BOX 951','CHICAGO','IL','60694-5124','','22 WINDSOCK CT','PO BOX 951'),
    ('1224483','Aerospace Junction','211500 Communicate Ave','Mingo Junction','OH','43939','USA','P O Box 99','Mingo Junction','OH','43939','USA','211500 Communicate Ave','PO Box 99'),
    ('1243397','Squeezy Felt','SCHREIBER DIST','NEW KENSINGTON','PA','15068','','','','','','','SCHREIBER DIST',''),
    ('1230895','NERO CO','28 North US State Highway 99','Osceola','AR','72370','USA','PO Box 204','Cape Girardeau','MO','63702-2045','USA','28 N US State Hwy 99','PO Box 204'),
    ('1243782','NERO CO','28 North US State Highway 99','Osceola','AR','72370','USA','PO Box 204','Cape Girardeau','MO','63702-2045','USA','28 N US State Hwy 99','PO Box 204'),
    ('1135880','RICHARD PRYOR SEMINARS','PO BOX 2194','KANSAS CITY','MO','64121-9468','USA','RICHARD PRYOR SEMINARS P O BOX 2194','KANSAS CITY','MO','64121-9468','USA','PO BOX 2194','RICHARD PRYOR SEMINARS PO BOX 2194'),
    ('1241328','INFINITY AND BEYOND','P.O. BOX 169','GASTONIA','NC','28053-0269','USA','','','','','','PO BOX 169',''),
    ('1259522','ZEEBO INC','PO BOX 169','GASSTONIA','NC','28053-0269','USA','','','','','','PO BOX 169',''),
    ('1255253','AT&T','PO Box 50221','Carol Stream','IL','60197','USA','','','','','','PO Box 50221',''),
    ('1135513','AT&T','PO Box 50221','Carol Stream','IL','60197-5080','USA','','','','','','PO Box 50221',''),
    ('1119161','Machine Co, Inc','3306 N Thorne Blvd','Chattanooga','TN','','','PO BOX 5301','CHATTANOOGA','TN','37406','USA','3306 N Thorne Blvd','PO BOX 5301'),
    ('1176587','Topsy Turvy','365 Welmington Road','Chicago','IL','60606','USA','','','','','','365 Welmington Rd',''),
    ('2156671','Topsy Turvvy, Inc.','P.O. Box 55217','Columbus','OH','43081','','365 Welmington Road','Chicago','IL','60606','USA','','365 Welmington Rd')
```

Original Results:

```
Reason  Supplier_No Name    Address City    State   Zip Country Remit_Address   Remit_City  Remit_State Remit_Zip   Remit_Country
Address Match   1218409 SouthWestern Medical    100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave Osceola AR  72370   USA
Address Match   1243789 SouthWestern Medical    100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA SouthWestern Medical100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA
Address Match   1230895 NERO CO 28 North US State Highway 99    Osceola AR  72370   USA PO Box 204  Cape Girardeau  MO  63702-2045  USA
Address Match   1243782 NERO CO 28 North US State Highway 99    Osceola AR  72370   USA PO Box 204  Cape Girardeau  MO  63702-2045  USA
Address Match   1176587 Topsy Turvy 365 Welmington Road Chicago IL  60606   USA                 
Address Match   2156671 Topsy Turvvy, Inc.  P.O. Box 55217  Columbus    OH  43081       365 Welmington Road Chicago IL  60606   USA
Address Match   1241328 INFINITY AND BEYOND P.O. BOX 169    GASTONIA    NC  28053-0269  USA                 
Address Match   1259522 ZEEBO INC   PO BOX 169  GASSTONIA   NC  28053-0269  USA                 
Address Match   1230895 NERO CO 28 North US State Highway 99    Osceola AR  72370   USA PO Box 204  Cape Girardeau  MO  63702-2045  USA
Address Match   1243782 NERO CO 28 North US State Highway 99    Osceola AR  72370   USA PO Box 204  Cape Girardeau  MO  63702-2045  USA
Address Match   1255253 AT&T    PO Box 50221    Carol Stream    IL  60197   USA                 
Address Match   1135513 AT&T    PO Box 50221    Carol Stream    IL  60197-5080  USA                 
Address Match   1218409 SouthWestern Medical    100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA Southern Lawn Care1004 W Hale Ave   Osceola AR  72370   USA
Address Match   1243789 SouthWestern Medical    100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA SouthWestern Medical100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA
```

Current Results:

```
Reason  Supplier_No Name    Address City    State   Zip Country Remit_Address   Remit_City  Remit_State Remit_Zip   Remit_Country
Address Match   1135513 AT&T    PO Box 50221    Carol Stream    IL  60197-5080  USA                 
Address Match   1255253 AT&T    PO Box 50221    Carol Stream    IL  60197   USA                 
Address Match   1241328 INFINITY AND BEYOND P.O. BOX 169    GASTONIA    NC  28053-0269  USA                 
Address Match   1243782 NERO CO 28 North US State Highway 99    Osceola AR  72370   USA PO Box 204  Cape Girardeau  MO  63702-2045  USA
Address Match   1230895 NERO CO 28 North US State Highway 99    Osceola AR  72370   USA PO Box 204  Cape Girardeau  MO  63702-2045  USA
Address Match   1218409 SouthWestern Medical    100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave Osceola AR  72370   USA
Address Match   1243789 SouthWestern Medical    100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA SouthWestern Medical100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA
Address Match   2156671 Topsy Turvvy, Inc.  P.O. Box 55217  Columbus    OH  43081       365 Welmington Road Chicago IL  60606   USA
Address Match   1176587 Topsy Turvy 365 Welmington Road Chicago IL  60606   USA                 
Address Match   1259522 ZEEBO INC   PO BOX 169  GASSTONIA   NC  28053-0269  USA
```

Desired Results:

```
Reason  Supplier_No Name    Address City    State   Zip Country Remit_Address   Remit_City  Remit_State Remit_Zip   Remit_Country
Address Match   1135513 AT&T    PO Box 50221    Carol Stream    IL  60197-5080  USA                 
Address Match   1255253 AT&T    PO Box 50221    Carol Stream    IL  60197   USA                 
Address Match   1241328 INFINITY AND BEYOND P.O. BOX 169    GASTONIA    NC  28053-0269  USA                 
Address Match   1259522 ZEEBO INC   PO BOX 169  GASSTONIA   NC  28053-0269  USA                                     
Address Match   1243782 NERO CO 28 North US State Highway 99    Osceola AR  72370   USA PO Box 204  Cape Girardeau  MO  63702-2045  USA
Address Match   1230895 NERO CO 28 North US State Highway 99    Osceola AR  72370   USA PO Box 204  Cape Girardeau  MO  63702-2045  USA
Address Match   1218409 SouthWestern Medical    100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA SouthWestern Medical100 W Balor Ave Osceola AR  72370   USA
Address Match   1243789 SouthWestern Medical    100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA SouthWestern Medical100 West Balor Ave  Osceola AR  72370   USA
Address Match   2156671 Topsy Turvvy, Inc.  P.O. Box 55217  Columbus    OH  43081       365 Welmington Road Chicago IL  60606   USA
Address Match   1176587 Topsy Turvy 365 Welmington Road Chicago IL  60606   USA
```

Comment: Voting to close as too broad, because I can't easily see a minimal problem here.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: UNION eliminates duplicate rows,  so no need to do SELECT DISTINCT. And those GROUP BYs are even more redundant.

Comment: @jarlh I changed the title so it's a bit more clear.  I have the dupe record removal taken care of, I need to now group the matched items together.  Since there is no good field to order on I don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do -- sort records with the same normalized address together?  that sounds like what you you want to  -- just use "RANK()" windowing function and then sort by that.

Comment: @Hogan That's the gist of it, but they can be matched to different fields.  Address of one record could be matched to Remit Address of another record.  In another data set I have two addresses with two address lines.  So I can't just take a single field into account.  I am not familiar with the RANK function.

Comment: @Hogan I read up on the RANK function and it seems like it would do the trick, but I don't get how/where to put it in my process.  I can change the CTE to a bunch of UNIONs but either way I don't understand how to get the RANK to work to mark the matched records as needed.

Comment: I don't understand this :  `( n.[NewAdd] = pv.[cleanAddress]       AND ( [Address]       <> '' AND [Address]       IS NOT NULL ) )  OR` why are you looking to see if NewAdd and cleanAddress are the same but this checking Address for null or empty?